# How do I create a relying party application in my Azure AD B2C using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a POST request that I am using to create a relying party application for my Azure AD Tenant.

POST
[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/{{tenant_id}}/applications](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/%7B%7Btenant_id%7D%7D/applications)

Headers:

```
Authorization: {{graph_access_token}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

Body:

```
{
    "displayName": "JWT.MS 8",
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "5b567255-7703-4780-807c-7be8301ae99b",
                    "type": "Role"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "6234d376-f627-4f0f-90e0-dff25c5211a3",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
    "web": {
        "redirectUris": [
            "https://jwt.ms/"
        ],
        "implicitGrantSettings": {
            "enableIdTokenIssuance": true,
            "enableAccessTokenIssuance": true
        }
    }
}
```

I receive a 201 created response for this application.

When I attempt to use this relying party via the authorize endpoint using an implicit flow I get the following error:

```
https://{{TenantName}}.b2clogin.com/{{TenantName}}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_TEST_SIGNIN_LATEST&client_id=f7d77147-383f-4da0-9ca4-5da5628574a4&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms%2F&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login
```

> AADB2C90018: The client id 'f7d77147-383f-4da0-9ca4-5da5628574a4'
> specified in the request is not registered in tenant
> '{{TenantName}}.onmicrosoft.com'.

In the Azure Portal I see that the API permissions are not granted.

[image: List of API Permissions for an Application created via Graph API]

How should the application be changed via the Graph API so that the relying application can be seen as registered in B2C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps will allow someone to create a relying party application for Azure AD B2C via Graph API:

[image]

The application that is used to retrieve the token requires the following permissions:

- https://graph.microsoft.com/Application.Read.All
- https://graph.microsoft.com/Application.ReadWrite.All
- https://graph.microsoft.com/Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy
- https://graph.microsoft.com/DelegatedPermissionGrant.ReadWrite.All

The POST applications request is in the question above.

The next step is to create a service principal for that application.

POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/{{tenant_id}}/servicePrincipals](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/%7B%7Btenant_id%7D%7D/servicePrincipals)

Headers:

```
Authorization: {{graph_access_token}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

Body

```
{
  "appId": "{{app_appId}}"
}
```

Where the `{{app_appId}}` is the `appId` taken from the response of POST /applications

The next request is granting the oauth2 permissions.

POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/{{tenant_id}}/oauth2PermissionGrants](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/%7B%7Btenant_id%7D%7D/oauth2PermissionGrants)

Header:

```
Authorization: {{graph_access_token}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

Body:

```
{
    "clientId": "{{service_principal_id}}",
    "consentType": "AllPrincipals",
    "expiryTime": "2030-05-12T00:00:00.9831598Z",
    "principalId": null,
    "resourceId": "{{graph_app_id}}",
    "scope": "openid offline_access"
}
```

Where the `{{service_principal_id}}` is the `id` from the POST /servicePrincipals response.

Where the `{{graph_app_id}}` is the `id` of the service principal with the displayName of "Microsoft Graph". This can be retrieved by the following request:

GET  https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/{{tenant_id}}/servicePrincipals?$filter=startswith(displayName,'Microsoft Graph')

Header:

```
Authorization: {{graph_access_token}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL request is correct

```
https://{{TenantName}}.b2clogin.com/{{TenantName}}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_TEST_SIGNIN_LATEST&client_id=f7d77147-383f-4da0-9ca4-5da5628574a4&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms%2F&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login
```

But an Azure AD B2C application should be created using the Azure AD B2C blade of the Azure Portal. You need to register your application by going to Azure AD B2C tenant and search for Azure AD B2C on Azure portal to register applications instead of going to normal Azure AD application registration page.Otherwise it become fault app and you then recieve

> AADB2C90018: The client id 'f7d77147-383f-4da0-9ca4-5da5628574a4'
> specified in the request is not registered in tenant
> '{{TenantName}}.onmicrosoft.com'.

If you have registered the application on Azure AD then delete those and register application on Azure AD B2C.

[image]

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/73443/the-client-id-39039-specified-in-the-request-is-no.html

Comment: I have worked out a way to create the application and have it successfully registered via Microsoft Graph. I will post an answer to the question.